# Linear line with customized max at a given time adding to Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I use Google chart to illustrate how many items have been sold of a given product. To give a hint how the selling is processing, I would like to add a linear line with min value 0 and max value (no of items that must be sold). Since there is only two points I can't add it to my others rows of data, since they have many points. I was looking for something like trendline, just where it is possible to set your min and max value. Is that possible or how can I make such a line ?